# GPG periodically loses connection to yubikey on monterey

Tags: gnupg, yubikey

The connection between gpg and my yubikey appears to periodically fail. Decryption attempts are met with the pinentry-mac dialog "please insert card with serial number X".

`gpg --card-status -v` reports

```
gpg: Note: RFC4880bis features are enabled.
gpg: selecting card failed: Operation not supported by device
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: Operation not supported by device
```

Reboot always resolves the issue, restarting the `gpg-agent` doesn't.

Using GPG 2.3.4 and macos monterey (issue also occured on catalina)

Any troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this on macOS 12.3.1 on M1/ARM, rebooting does not fix it.  Also on GPG 2.3.4 (from nixpkgs, current in nixpkgs as of today).

I found the fix to be:

```
SCDAEMON_CONF="disable-ccid\nreader-port \"$(pcsctest <<< 01 | grep 'Reader 01' | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}' | head -n1)\""
echo $SCDAEMON_CONF > ~/.gnupg/scdaemon.conf
gpgconf --kill all
```

(from https://github.com/DataDog/yubikey/blob/master/lib/scdaemon.sh )

This made `gpg --card-status` work again, and `ssh-add -L` shows my gpg smartcard (on Yubikey) in the keylist (via gpg-agent) again.